# Asynchronous control without QTimer

Tags: qt, asynchronous

Is there any way to have a higher performance asynchronous processing without using `QTimer`?

Essentially I have a `single_step` function that either should be invoked once the "single step" button is pressed, or in a loop after "start" button is pressed, until the "stop" button is pressed.

`QTimer` with `0` delay time works just fine, but the performance is a bit slow. I'm looking for replacements.

Comment: @user3528438 How is that asynchronous?

Comment: if you do it in a different thread then it is, like using `QtConcurrent::run`. But I believe the problem is that you are using the QTimer in the main thread, which could be packed with UI events. If you move the work to a different thread, and maybe give it a higher priority than main thread, performance would improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` with `Qt::QueuedConnection`.

I don't know if it is going to be any faster. The main source of overhead will still be the event system. You deffinitely **do not want** asynchronicity to be too fine grained.

Answer (score 0):

The `single_step` function does too little work. You should invoke it multiple times in a row, e.g.:

```
class Worder : public QObject {
  QBasicTimer m_timer;
  ...
  void single_step();
  void work_chunk() { for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) single_step(); }
  ...
  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent* ev) {
    if (ev->timerId() == m_timer.timerId())
      work_chunk();
  }
};
```